# How can I transfer this information from my button selection (font size) to a php script, and than save the information to mysql?

Tags: php, css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><body>

<p id="myP">This is a paragraph.</p> // txt paragraph

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Small</button> // button one

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Bigger</button> // button two

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction3()">Large</button> // button three


<script>

function myFunction() { // functon to first button

document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = "x-small";    

}

</script>


<script>

function myFunction2() {// functon to second button

document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = "x-large";    

}

</script>


<script>

function myFunction3() { // functon to third button

 document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = "xx-large";  

}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: provide more details about your question along with code

Answer (score 0):

For neatness i'd update the scripts first to take a variable, that way you only need to write it once something like

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('small')">Small</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('bigger')">Bigger</button>
```

then when writing your function employ something like AJAX to push the selected option to another page that simply reads in a post variable and pushes to mysql

```
<script>
  function myfunction(fontSize){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/some/url',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { var1: fontSize } ,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (response) {
        // reload items on page if required;
      },
      error: function () {
        // do something with your error
      }
    });

  }
</script>
```

In your URL you enter on the url line just handle a post variable then add the details into mysql in whatever way you tend to use. You can also put things like CRF_Tokens into the request for a bit more security.

I am assuming you also have a user account or something that may need to be posted along with the variable, this can be handled the same way just append extra items to data separated by a comma i.e.

```
data: { var1: fontSize, var2: userId, var3: csrfToken }
```

NOTE: You will need jquery added to your code for ajax to work, and an understanding of AJAX, head to: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more info